# Jenkins pipeline job's config.xml resetting to cloned tasks default parameter values on build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 1 pipeline job in Jenkins that was used as a template to create 7 more jobs using the "Copy From" option.  Each job has is "This project is parameterized" with the same parameters, BUT different "Default Values". 
The Build Description is also different across those 7 new jobs, but this never changes.  The problem is, when any of the 7 jobs are run, the "Default Values" change back to their original values from when they were created.  So after all 7 run, they ALL have the same default values as the first job they were cloned from.   I actually see the config.xml file change right after they are scheduled.  I don't see any links in the XML that would indicate it would copy the default values either, what mechanism is changing this?  How does it know what to change it to?  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
    <?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<flow-definition plugin="workflow-job@2.19">
  <actions>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.JobPropertyTrackerAction plugin="workflow-multibranch@2.17">
      <jobPropertyDescriptors>
        <string>hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty</string>
        <string>com.sonyericsson.rebuild.RebuildSettings</string>
      </jobPropertyDescriptors>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.JobPropertyTrackerAction>
  </actions>
  <description>RSYS2_Regression&#xd;
Runs on RSYS2 machines (201.4 - 201.5 - 201.6)&#xd;
</description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
      <strategy class="hudson.tasks.LogRotator">
        <daysToKeep>31</daysToKeep>
        <numToKeep>-1</numToKeep>
        <artifactDaysToKeep>30</artifactDaysToKeep>
        <artifactNumToKeep>-1</artifactNumToKeep>
      </strategy>
    </jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.DisableConcurrentBuildsJobProperty/>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.DurabilityHintJobProperty>
      <hint>MAX_SURVIVABILITY</hint>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.DurabilityHintJobProperty>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty>
      <triggers>
        <hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
          <spec>30 20 * * 1-5 

30 5 * * 1-5
</spec>
        </hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
      </triggers>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty>
    <com.sonyericsson.rebuild.RebuildSettings plugin="rebuild@1.28">
      <autoRebuild>false</autoRebuild>
      <rebuildDisabled>false</rebuildDisabled>
    </com.sonyericsson.rebuild.RebuildSettings>
    <hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
      <parameterDefinitions>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
          <name>Tag</name>
          <description>BDD Cucumber Tag</description>
          <defaultValue>all</defaultValue>
          <trim>true</trim>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
          <name>Branch</name>
          <description>Github Branch</description>
          <defaultValue>master</defaultValue>
          <trim>true</trim>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
          <name>LogLevel</name>
          <description>Level of logging</description>
          <defaultValue>Trace</defaultValue>
          <trim>true</trim>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
      </parameterDefinitions>
    </hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
  </properties>
```

In this example, Parameter definitions for "tag, branch and trace levels" all get reset.  Build description and timer trigger stay as they were saved.

Comment: What does your build script look like - could not make it out in the xml? Are you using any `properties` step by chance?

Comment: Yes, at the top of the groovy script, there is a properties step... so you're saying that that will overwrite whats in the build job defaults in Jenkins?
     `properties([[$class: 'RebuildSettings', autoRebuild: false, rebuildDisabled: false], parameters([string(defaultValue: 'all', description: 'BDD Cucumber Tag', name: 'Tag', trim: true), string(defaultValue: 'master', description: 'Github Branch', name: 'Branch', trim: true), string(defaultValue: 'Trace' `
.... etc

Comment: Exactly, that will overwrite the settings in Jenkins. What do you expect it would do ;)

Comment: @JoergS Life saver!  thank you!